# Javascript multiple asignment re-evaluation or result passing?

Tags: javascript, optimization, variable-assignment

The *multiple assignment* (or is it called *chaining*?) that I'm talking about is assignment such as:

```
a = b = c = 2;
```

...after which `a`, `b`, and `c` are all equal to 2;

My question of optimization is, given the following code:

```
var dom1 = document.getElementById('layout_logos');
var dom2 = document.getElementById('layout_sitenav');
...
function layout_onscroll(){
  ...
  dom1.style.height = dom2.style.top = maxLogoHeight - scrollTop;
  ...
}
```

From what I've been reading, I'm afraid the code in `layout_onscroll` is evaluating to:

```
dom2.style.top = maxLogoHeight - scrollTop;
dom1.style.height = dom2.style.top;
```

.. which gives the right value but accesses dom2 twice -- once to set `top` and once to get `top`. (note I'm coming from a .NET background where Microsoft wraps everything in layers upon layers of accessor functions making loops using those buried variables prohibitively slow.)

If so, is it faster to create an additional variable and then assign both DOM elements to that variable?

```
  ...
  var temp_var = maxLogoHeight - scrollTop;
  dom1.style.height = temp_var;
  dom2.style.top = temp_var;
  ...
```

The obvious loss doing that comes from allocating the temp var every time. But if `dom2.style.top` is accessed by two getter functions under the hood (e.g. if the first version calls `dom2.getStyle().getTop()` which in turn parses all the text of `dom2`'s css for the word 'top') then allocating a temp var may be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
dom1.style.height = dom2.style.top = maxLogoHeight - scrollTop;
```

… is not quite the same as this:

```
dom2.style.top = maxLogoHeight - scrollTop;
dom1.style.height = dom2.style.top;
```

Instead, the right-hand operand `maxLogoHeight - scrollTop` is assigned to *each* of `dom1.style.height` and `dom2.style.top`.

We can see this in the following example:

**Snippet**

```js
var d= document.getElementById('D');

s = d.style.width= 'abc';
console.log(s);             //'abc'

d.style.width= 'abc';
s= d.style.width;
console.log(s);             //null string
```

```css
#D {height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red;}
```

```html
<div id="D"></div>
```

`abc` is an invalid width, and it is therefore discarded by `d.style.width`.  However, you'll see that `s` is assigned `abc` in the first `console.log()`, and it's assigned the null string in the second `console.log()`.

---

The following example may be more intuitive:

```js
const x = 3;
var y = x = 6;                   // x cannot change.  So is y 3 or 6?
document.body.innerHTML= x + y;  // -> 9 ... y must be 6!
```

Comment: Perfect! I never thought to pass an invalid value through to a variable. Brilliant example.