# Why Initialization of several variables leading into Scope Leakage?

Tags: javascript, scope

I was referring docs of JavaScript `var hoisting` , There in a section i found [Initialization of several variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) with a [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/c7x87Lxo/) given below.

```
var x = 0;

function f(){
  var x = y = 1; 
}
f();

console.log(x, y); // outputs 0, 1
// x is the global one as expected
// y leaked outside of the function, though!
```

Where I Suppose to get Exception as `Uncaught Reference Error: y is not defined`.
but it is not happening due to leaked Scope and it is displaying `0,1`.

Can I Know why it is happening in detail and what made this to happen.
Finally any performance related issues ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is setting multiple variables in 1 line valid in javascript? (var x=y='value';)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581439/is-setting-multiple-variables-in-1-line-valid-in-javascript-var-x-y-value)

Comment: Its not a question related to possibilities for `initialization of several variables`  but with  variable `Scope` changes  @torazaburo.

Comment: Read the proposed duplicate more closely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not declaring `y`.

```
var x = y = 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
y = 1;
var x = y; // actually, the right part is precisely the result of the assignement
```

An [undeclared variable is a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope) (unless you're in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), then it's an error).

The example you're referring to was different, there was a **comma**, which [is part of the multiple declaration syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Declaring_and_initializing_two_variables).

You could fix your code in

```
var y=1, x=y;
```

Comment: Actually, the original code is equivalent to `y=1; var x=1;`.  If `y` couldn't be assigned to 1 for whatever reason, `x` would still equal 1.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31414927/3903374

Comment: @RickHitchcock More precisely, it's the value of the (y=1) expression. Saying it's 1 is equivalent in that case to saying it's y.

Comment: Correct in this instance, but that was the assumption in my linked post, which was incorrect in that instance.  If `y` were previously declared as a `const` 2, `x` would *not* equal 2.